# THREE.js - morphTargetInfluences on an imported JSON mesh not getting results

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I have a basic three.js scene in which I am attempting to get objects exported from Blender (as JSON files with embedded morphs) to function and update their shapes with user input.

Here is a test scene
http://onthez.com/temphosting/three-js-morph-test/morph-test.html

The slab is being resized without morphs by simply scaling a box, which is working just fine.

I must be missing something fundamental with the little monument on top.  It has 3 morphs (width, depth, height) that are intended to allow it to resize.

I am using this code to implement the morph based on users dat.gui input.

```
folder1.add( params, 'width', 12, 100 ).step(1).name("Width").onChange( function () {
  updateFoundation();
  building.morphTargetInfluences['width'] = params.width/100;
  roofL.morphTargetInfluences['width'] = params.width/100;
  roofR.morphTargetInfluences['width'] = params.width/100;
  building.updateMorphs();
});
```

The materials for building, roofL, and roofR each have morphTargets set as true.
I've been going over the three.js examples here:
http://threejs.org/examples/?q=morph#webgl_morphtargets_human
as well as #webgl_morphtargets and #webgl_morphtargets_horse

Any thoughts or input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've reached a solution for my question  I was under the impression that the JSON loader was preserving the morph target names to be used in place of an index number with morphTargetInfluences

something like morphTargetInfluences['myMorphTargetName']
but, after closer inspection in the console it seems like they should be referred to by number like morphTargetInfluences[0]

Not the most intuitive, but I can work with it.

Comment: To expound on this a bit further, I notice morphTargetDictionary[] can help with this by associating the name of each morph target with it's assigned index. Using myObject.morphTargetInfluences[myObject.morphTargetDictionary['myMorphTargetName']] = 1; gets the proper morph target and applies the value.